# How to get data from picker through v-model in framework7?

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, html-framework-7

I have created text input field like below,

```
<f7-list-item>
          <f7-icon slot="media" f7="time"></f7-icon>
            <f7-input type="text" placeholder="Delivery time" v-model="order.time" readonly id="picker-describe"></f7-input>
</f7-list-item>

Now in mounted method, I have the below code,
mounted: function mounted() {
          //do something after mounting vue instance
      var myApp = new Framework7();
      var pickerDescribe = myApp.picker({
          input: '#picker-describe',
          rotateEffect: true,
          cols: [
            // Hours
            {
                values: (function () {
                    var arr = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) { arr.push(i); }
                    return arr;
                })(),
            },
            // Divider
            {
                divider: true,
                content: ':'
            },
            // Minutes
            {
                values: (function () {
                    var arr = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 59; i++) { arr.push(i < 10 ? ': 0' + i : ": " + i); }
                    return arr;
                })(),
            },
            // Meridian
            {
                values: (function () 
                {
                    var arr = ['am','pm'];
                    return arr;
                })(),
            }
          ]
      });
    },
```

When I try to select the time, I'm able to select the time happily like below,

[image: time selecting page]

Now I'm trying to get the value through the model, I'm getting empty on order.time field.

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to get the time field data through the model?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did this by using v-on:click=onChange on picker field,

```
<f7-list-item>
          <f7-icon slot="media" f7="time"></f7-icon>
          <f7-input type="text" class="delivery-time" v-on:change='changeTime()' placeholder="Delivery time" v-model="order.deliveryTime" readonly id="picker-describe"></f7-input>
</f7-list-item>
```

Here is the code how I solved this puzzle,

I did this for 24 hours time format that to i added ':0' again to the date.

```
changeTime () {
                var $$ = Dom7;
                var date = $$('#picker-describe').val();
                this.order.deliveryTime = date + ':0';
            },
```

Now i have time data in,

```
order: {
    "deliveryTime":''
}
```

I'm able to get time data by accessing like `this.order.deliveryTime` whenever it got changed. This is just an alternate, there must be something else to this scenario.

Thanks,